# react-router: Not render component after url updater

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I use

```
"react": "^16.5.0",
"react-router": "^4.3.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
```

Has router

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import GoToNode from './components/map/GoToNode';

const Router = (props) => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/*/node/:nodeId" component={GoToNode} />
        </Switch>
    );
};

export default Router;
```

When I refresh  page 'localhost:3000/project/node/5' router renders GoToNode component. When I use function 'selectNode' from another component GoToNode is not been rendered.

```
selectNode(node: Node) {
    this.props.history.push(`/project/node/${node.objectId}`); 
}
...
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NodeWorkingList));
```

Do you have any idea why? Thanks! :)

Comment: Is your `URL` changing ?

Comment: Yes, URL is changing. But router is not been called.

Comment: wrap the switch inside `<BrowserRouter>` and try.

Comment: I have it already around ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={storeSetup.store}>
      <PersistGate ...>
        <Route path="/" component={App} />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement 
);

Comment: Added as you said, it did not help.